# CAN I GET MY MONEY BACK FROM AN OLD MYCELIUM WALLET ? I HAVE THE BITCOIN ADDRESS MYCELIUM SUPPORT SUCKS NO HELP AT ALL

Tags: money

CAN I GET MY MONEY BACK FROM MYCELIUM I HAVE MY BITCOIN ADDRESS  THERE SUPPORT SUCKS MYCELIUM CRASHED THEY GAVE ME A NEW WALLET BUT I HAD MONEY ON THE OLD ONE I CAN NOT GET THERE SUPPORT WILL NOT ANSWER ME

Comment: Do you remember making a [backup](https://cryptopotato.com/mycelium-wallet-complete-guide/) of the old wallet? If so you should have a secret 12 word phrase written down (never give this to anyone else, not even helpers).

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have access to the old wallet on an old phone perhaps?

If, so you should look into exporting your private keys and then you can use any other preferred wallet and import the same set of keys and youre good to go :)